# Will we be able to change the site name before launch?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, beta-phase

[Robert mentions in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same) that the community will choose the theme of a new StackExchange 2.0 site before it launches.

What about the site name?  Most proposals have very descriptive titles, but I presume some people would prefer names more akin to what "stackoverflow" is for programming?  And related to this, can we have distinct domain names, or will they be blah.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the private beta e-mail I received:

> At the end of 60 to 90 days, if the site has enough ongoing traffic and enough questions are getting answers, it will graduate to a full-fledged, permanent Stack Exchange. At that time the community will decide on a permanent, **top-level URL**, a web design and a logo.

(my bold)

So yes, the site name will be "up for grabs" as I would assume that the top level URL will be:

> www.sitename.com

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. [This answer over here on stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/739/please-add-a-key-fields-to-stackauth-results/754#754) guarantees that `site_name` will be fixed and never change. The sites have been added to StackApps (No access to the private beta? You can view it through a selection of the apps on StackApps - shameless plug for my apps [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu) and [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/570/saggregator-a-way-to-accumulate-all-the-latest-activity-from-the-stackapps-api)) so I would assume that the names are fixed?

Otherwise, someone at the API has been telling porkies.

Comment: Maybe the original name will continue to exist and work for Stack Apps.

Comment: I doubt it - if the stackapps name is wrong then users of stackapps apps won't easily be able to make the link between a SA and the SE version of the site. "Web Apps" is its SA name, but if they decide to call it say "Attack of the Web Apps" the distinction may not be immediate, and if it's an even less similar name then...

Comment: note the note in that comment: "There might be some goofiness with area51 created sites in this regard, we'll keep you posted when the details shake out."

Answer (score 1):

From the "Create a Proposal" page's "Choose a Topic" pop-up help:

> Be concise, and specific.
>
> Examples: "Pets", "Personal Finance",
>   "Endodontics". You don't need a clever
>   name yet.
>
> Don't use the words "Site" or "Stack
>   Exchange".

I assume that *yet* means that the community will get to choose later.