# What appearance will Beta Stack Exchange sites have when they come out of Beta phase?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

I am a member of many of the Beta (and non-Beta) Stack Exchange sites and was wondering what appearance will the Beta Stack Exchange sites have when they come out of the Beta phase? Who will make this decision? What choices will they get?

Update:

I know this question is similar to [Will all Stack Exchange sites look the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same) but I was more interested in knowing what they will look like rather than if they will all be the same. Will the design be related to the subject matter of each site?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Our crack design team will work with the community (on each site's *meta*) to gather ideas for a design for the site. Then he (THEM! I MEANT THEM!) will propose two possible design ideas for the community to vote on, and anybody in the community who is interested in submitting their own design ideas can do so, too.

After some discussion the best design idea will be voted on by the community, and our crack designer (TEAM! HE'S A TEAM!) will work up that final awesome design.

**Each site will have its own design** although they will certainly share enough elements that they will all feel like a part of the awesome Stack Exchange Family.

Comment: Who is he ... I mean ... the team ?

Comment: Thanks Joel, I am assuming your crack design team consists of Jin Yang and his minions (or imaginary friends or split personalities)? :)

Comment: Shh... Don't tell anyone. For *your* eyes only: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/

Comment: cool, will be expecting something awesome from [him|them]. Btw, I feel honoured to have had responses from 2 of the main guys of Stack Exchange - great job on creating such a fantastic on-line community.

Comment: @Piers My unicorn and robot friends are not imaginary. We engage in deep conversations late at night about design and life in general. Also, what Joel said. I'll be making posts on some Meta SE sites very soon to gather design ideas from the community!

Comment: ^^^ Translation: Get involved in your Stack Exchange meta!