# Adverts for interesting question for a SE with a design appears as beta design

Tags: discussion

A recent side advert for a question on UX.SE ([this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/whats-the-point-in-electronic-devices-beeping-on-keypress)) appeared with the squared paper beta design background, is this because UX.SE is still in beta or does a site's design need to include these ads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ads are most likely computer-generated as they seem to be based on [the hottest questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected). The scripts probably take into account of the "beta-ness" of the site in question and render the beta design accordingly. And since UX.SE is in beta:

[image: ux.se beta screenshot]

The ads for UX.SE ends up with [the "sketchy beta" design](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) as a result.

---

Although UX.SE seems to be the exception to [this meta SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same/55542#55542):

> That is the "Sketchy" beta theme for all beta sites. When a site makes
> it out of beta, they will choose their own logo and design.

Comment: Had assumed so, had also wondered the formula for hot questions.