# Why is User Experience the exception?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites

Why is it that UX.Se is the exception to the [rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same/55542#55542) with their site design?

It [was shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102467/adverts-for-interesting-question-for-a-se-with-a-design-appears-as-beta-design) that UX is still in public beta.

What is the process in which a logo and design is created for beta sites?

Comment: Wow. I thought UX had graduated, entirely because it wasn't Sketchy. (In my defense, I never use that site, and I've visited it _maybe_ twice.)

Comment: To new readers: The UX site has now actually graduated, but they had got their finished design while still in beta.

Answer (score 7):

> When a site makes it out of beta, they will choose their own logo and design.

Nothing prohibits them from choosing their own logo and design at an earlier point; however, it is required to have your own logo and design for the site to get out of beta. For a UX Experience site, having an early good design on their site is crucial. Why would want discuss UX in a Sketchy theme?

> I feel it takes away the consitency of the SE site as a whole to have 1 site that hasn't reached full site-hood have a full design when the others don't.

Stack Exchange have their own designers, they usually come into play once the site gets out of beta.

> What is the process in which a logo and design is created for beta sites?

It's part of the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it that UX.Se is the exception to the rule with their site design?

User experience :P.  I would assume the UX site has a complete design because it's about UX. It would be ironic in a way if they didn't.

See [Jin's post](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/design-for-ux-se):

> For the UX.se site, the stats aren't quite there for an official launch just yet. However, I believe deploying a final design of the site would help to engage new UX users who aren't familiar with the Stack Exchange sites.

See also: [Who are the artists and designers doing the Stack Exchange sites' excellent artwork?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87220/who-are-the-artists-and-designers-doing-the-stack-exchange-sites-excellent-artw) and [Who designs the logos for Area 51 proposals?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/who-designs-the-logos-for-area-51-proposals)

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I feel it takes away the consitency of the SE site as a whole to have 1 site that hasn't reached full site-hood have a full design when the others don't. Which could argue that it goes against the UX of SE itself, lol...

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: But would all those other sites be able to design the site for themselves and still be attractive to a general audience?  I think the members of UX would be perfectly capable to provide one while the team's position is to wait until the site is ready to design one for them.